# Bootstrap Modal with File upload doesnt show uploaded images in browser :/

Tags: php, jquery, upload, modal-dialog, getfiles

My image upload modal doesn't work as expected. 
When I click on image upload button of the modal, image is perfectly saved in my server. But, the loaded image doesn't show up in the modal after upload... I need the image to appear in the modal (right after upload) for selection. If I clear the browser cache and delete all cookies, the uploaded images then shows up as it should in the modal. But I can't clear browser cache after each image upload, to be able to select the uploaded image... This is really embarrassing. I think there's something missing in my get_files.php codes. I'll share all codes below. Please, please , please help me solve this... Thanks a lot in advance. Have a great day !

I have tried many changes in php and js files but none of them worked :(

Here's a video url showing the problem: 'New uploaded images doesn't show up in modal, if browser cache is not cleaned ' : 
http://kartella.com.tr/modal.mp4

```js
<!--Get-Files.php-->

<?php
include_once 'config.php';

//get all files in uploads folder
$files = array_diff(scandir(UPLOADS_DIRECTORY), array('.', '..'));

//creating response
$response=array();

$response['code']=0;
$response['files']=$files;
$response['directory']=UPLOADS_URL;

//convert to json
echo json_encode($response);
?>

---JS Codes---

//load all uploads files from server
function loadImages() {
    /*<div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="fd" alt='' data-url=''>
     </div>*/
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get-files.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.code == 0) {
                _output = '';
                for (var k in data.files) {
                    if (typeof data.files[k] !== 'function') {
                        _output += "<div class='col-sm-3'>" +
                            "<img class='upload-image-item' src='" + data.directory + data.files[k] + "' alt='" + data.files[k] + "' data-url='" + data.directory + data.files[k] + "'>" +
                            "</div>";
                        // console.log("Key is " + k + ", value is" + data.files[k]);
                    }
                }
                $('.upload-images').html(_output);
            }
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
}

---PHP Codes---

onPopupUploadImageButtonClick: function() {
                console.log('onPopupUploadImageButtonClick html');
                var file_data = $('.input-file').prop('files')[0];
                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('file', file_data);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script
                    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_data,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(php_script_response) {
                        loadImages();
                    }
                });
            }
```

I would like the uploaded images to appear in the upload modal, immediately right after upload, without the need of cleaning the browser's cache.

Comment: I'd interested to know why the images should appear in the modal only after the upload succeeded? Why not show it before the upload? Using Javascript?

Comment: The images uploaded in the past already appear in the modal. The problem is that, the new uploaded ones does not appear in the modal, unless if you clear browser cache. So each time you need to upload a new image, in order to be able to select them, you need to clear browser cache so that they can appear in modal for selection. I would like to fix this problem. But I couldnt find out how... Any ideas ? Thanks so much...

Comment: Hi, it seems that you took my feedback (elsewhere) as constructive and reacted to it. Thank you. If you have any question on what I commented on the two posts you deleted elsewhere, I will happily clarify. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks Yunnosch. All is good. I am just new here. Trying to learn :)